# Event driven buffering vs timer driven buffering

Tags: .net-core, buffer, core-audio, buffering

I was currently reading some docs about the .NET Core Audio API.
I saw two SDK samples called [CaptureSharedEventDriven](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CaptureSharedTimerDriven](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So, I was wondering what's the difference between event driven buffering and timer driven buffering. Could someone please explain it to me :)

Thanks